# SPServices IE Issue GetListItems

Tags: spservices, internet-explorer

Ok, so here's the rundown.  I have a site with three child sites, and I am trying to get a rollup of content from these three sites.  Each site has the same list of "Initiatives" and on the parent site the client would like to see All of the initiatives.  This works fantastically in FF, however i just get an exception thrown in IE.  Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var subSite = new Array();

        $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Webs > Web").each(function() {
                var $node = $(this);
                var siteTitle = $node.attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, "");
                subSite.push( siteTitle );
            });
            }
        }); 

        for(i=0;i<4;i++){       
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                webURL: "/"+subSite[i]+"",
                async: false,
                listName: "Initiatives",
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
                completefunc: function(xData, Status){

                    alert(xData.responseText);
                    console.log( xData.responseText );
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
                        var liHtml = "<li><a href='/"+subSite[i]+"/SitePages/InitiativeOverview.aspx?"+$(this).attr('ows_Title')+"'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</a></li>";
                        $("#initiativeList").append(liHtml);
                    });//end xData
                }//end function
            });//end SPServices
        }//end for
    });
    </script>
```

Any thoughts or guidance is greatly appreciated.  I don't know why this wouldn't work, I have tried using the alternative z\:row in the SPFilterNode and it still returns nothing but an exception.

The exception is:

```
LOG: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring><detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">There is no Web named "/undefined/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx".</errorstring></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Again, thanks for any input!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `async: false,` on the first SPServices call to get the sites, so IE is probably just behaving as expected and continues to make the new requests without anything entered into subSites.

I don't know why FF fails to run the request async, but that just shows you shouldn't use that if you want right behaviour

Comment: This was it, Dumb...Dumb...Dumb...  Thanks Per Jakobsen

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that something gets screwed up in this line:
webURL: "/"+subSite[i]+"" as the error states: There is no Web named "/**undefined**/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

If you debug the for loop, are you getting results for all the iterations?

Comment: It is getting stopped there.  I changed the line for(i=1...) and it is still coming accross as undefined the first loop through, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix (and better codeing practice) would be to change your for loop to something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<subSite.count();i++){
```

Based on your code it seems like you want to loop through every site returned, not 4 sites regardless of how many sites are returned.  As far as why a different number of sites are being returned in IE vs FF, I'm not quite sure.  If you post your `xData.responseXML` from IE and from FF, I might be able to help more.

Comment: The same number of sites are being returned in FF, and the same exception is being thrown in FF however FF just ignores it and keeps chugging.

Comment: Can you post your `xData.responseXML`?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring><detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">There is no Web named "/GST/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx".</errorstring></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: Not sure if that's what you want?

Comment: It's the `xData.responseXML` from the first request we need to see why you don't get the site information when running IE

Comment: @BrentonPierce, no.  As Per mentioned, I need to see the `xData.responseXML`.  If you have FireBug or Developer tools you can place a break point there and inspect the value.

Comment: Abe, Not sure which line to put the breakpoint on?  I should probly learn to use the debugger.  Where do you find the xData.responseXML in firebug once you have put the breakpoint in?

Comment: Put it here: `$(xData.responseXML)`.  Once it hits the break point you can probably just mouse over or add it to your watch list.